# Find and Rank Time Series MATLAB

Tags: matlab, find, match, time-series, rank

I know there must be a simple way that I can learn to do this but I cannot imagine how to start.  I am tasked with finding a top 10 matching daily wind power time series in a 30-day plus/minus window from the first day in the time series (Jan 1st) matching a single daily wind power time series and it is out of my level of experience in MATLAB.  I have successfully done this matching a single time series of the current year with the exact calendar days from previous years, but I need a more robust searching method to find the best correlated time series in a +/- window of time.  For example, I'm comparing a 120 day time series (without leap years) with 25 previous years during the same 120-day period (Jan-Apr).  The end result will show me the top 10 time series with the years and Julian day or cumulative day listed and a correlation or RMSE value associated with it.  My data looks like this arranged in a 365 (days) X 25 (years) array and I thank you very much for your help!
     1182573      470528     1638232     2105034     1070466      478257     1096999
      879997      715531     1111498     1004556     1894202     1372178     1707984
      636173      937769     2119436      742710     1625931     1275567     1228515
      967360     1103082     2218855     1643898     1822868      554769     1325642

Comment: or those data points at the end? anyway, just to clear things up you have a  (years)x(days)x(pointsperday) array of historical data and you have a timeseries of 30days and you find the best matching 30days timeperiod somewhere in there?

Comment: Hi - yes they are data points at the end above but it could just be random numbers.  Yes, my data is a 365 days X 25 years array and I am trying to match a 120 day period from the current year (2016) against the other 25 years in the 365 X 25 array. I'm trying to find the best 120 day match period from 2016 yr to the other 25 yrs in a +/- 30 day window from Jan 1st.  So, ultimately, there will be a 120X25X60 array matched against the 120X1 array and final result will be top 10 list by days and yrs of the best matched 120 day periods from the 60-day window.  I hope this makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: The matching 120-day period from 2016 could be a 60 or 90 day user-chosen period from 2016 instead of the 120-day period starting Jan 1st.

Comment: is that issue still unsolved?